# how to change int array to real numbers(double or float) array

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote a program which opperate with int elements in array. How to change it if I want to enter a real numbers(0.01 and etc) in to arrays. I tried to change `int array[]`, to `double array[]` . but still my porgram not reachint in "." is like space and if "," code stops. Any advices?

```
    int size1, size2, size,i,mul;
        double arr1[100], arr2[100],merge[200];
        mul=1;
        cout<<"Enter Array 1 Size : ";
        cin>>size1;
        cout<<"Enter Array 1 Elements : ";
        for(i=0; i<size1; i++)
        {
            cin>>arr1[i];

        }
        cout<<"Enter Array 2 Size : ";
        cin>>size2;
        cout<<"Enter Array 2 Elements : ";
        for(i=0; i<size2; i++)
        {
            cin>>arr2[i];

        }
int negativecount = 0;
for(i=0; i<size1; i++)
{
    if(arr1[i]<0)
    {
      merge[negativecount++]=arr1[i];
    }
}
size=size1+size2;
for(i=0; i<size2 && negativecount < size; i++)
{
    if(arr2[i]<0)
    {
        merge[negativecount++]=arr2[i];
    }
}
for(i = 0; i < negativecount; ++i)
{
    mul = mul * merge[i];
}
    cout <<"Value of muliplyed array numbers:"<<mul << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `double` is certainly the right idea to start with, but you do not provide enough information do diagnose the problem. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] including the actual and the desired behavior.

Comment: For understand your question add some code

Comment: reachint ? do you mean read int?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I added my arrays adding part

Comment: @Pr0t3 Looks fine so far, at least as long you read at most 100 numbers per array. Please make sure your minimal example actually reproduces the problem. As this is input related, you should also include the input you used.

Comment: @BaummitAugen as I said everything works with int numbers in input. But if I use real numbers it stops working.

Comment: @Pr0t3 As I said, the code you show is not the problem. Also *"it stops working."* is not a useful problem statement.

Comment: @BaummitAugen so where can be the problem? IF it is almoust all my code. So If I use numbers with like(2.2), that "." is used like a space. IF I use "2,2" it prints all cout lines and (even which should be called) and you can't do anything :/ . maybe its problem I use int main()?

Comment: @Pr0t3 I cannot tell you what is wrong, I don't know the code. The link in my first comment can help you narrow down the issue. All I can see is that the code you posted works: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95310282f6145671

Comment: @BaummitAugen I added all the code. Maybe it is becouse multiplying the floats I am not getting correct value?

Comment: One issue is that `mul` should be a `double`. If that does not solve it, please post your input and your actual and desired output.

Comment: @BaummitAugen thank you, I don't know how I forget that :/